# Log4j not working with Jboss 7 AS

Tags: log4j, jboss7.x

I have configured my EJB with my custom log4j here's my log4j xml file

```
<appender name="sptLogs" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">

    <param name="File" value="D:/temp/logs/sm-ent/support.log" />

    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">

        <!-- <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n" /> -->

        <param name="ConversionPattern"    value="%d{DATE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />

    </layout>



    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">

        <param name="LevelMin" value="INFO" />

        <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL" />

    </filter>



</appender>



<appender name="appLogs" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">



    <param name="File" value="D:/temp/logs/sm-ent/app.log" />

    <!--

    <param name="File" value="/usr/local/2-tomcat_integration/webapps/SanMarWebService/logs/app.log"/>

     -->

    <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>

    <param name="Append" value="true" />

    <param name="maxFileSize" value="5MB" />

    <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="20" />

    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">

    <!--  <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n" /> -->

        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{DATE} %-5p %-15c{1}:%M() %m%n"/>

    </layout>



    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">

        <param name="LevelMin" value="DEBUG" />

        <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL" />

    </filter>

</appender>



<appender name="errorfile" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">

    <param name="maxFileSize" value="500KB" />

    <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="20" />



    <param name="File" value="D:/temp/logs/sm-ent/errors.log" />

    <!--

    <param name="File" value="/usr/local/2-tomcat_integration/webapps/SanMarWebService/logs/errors.log" />

    -->

    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">

        <param name="ConversionPattern"    value="%d{DATE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />

    </layout>

    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">

        <param name="LevelMin" value="error" />

        <param name="LevelMax" value="fatal" />

    </filter>

</appender>



<logger name="com.sanmar">

    <level value="DEBUG"/>

      <appender-ref ref="sptLogs"/>

</logger>



<root>

    <level value="TRACE" />

    <appender-ref ref="appLogs" />

    <appender-ref ref="errorfile" />

</root>
```

I am using spring to initialize LOG4J using the spring bean like this

```
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">

    <property name="targetClass"

        value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" />

    <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />

    <property name="arguments">

        <list>           

                 <value>D:\temp\properties\sm-enterprise-log4j.xml</value>                                   

        </list>

    </property>

</bean>
```

But I am getting the error

```
15:57:39,667 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1) java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender cannot be cast to org.apache.log4j.Appender



15:57:39,668 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:238)



15:57:39,670 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:171)



15:57:39,670 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:184)



15:57:39,671 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:502)



15:57:39,672 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseCategory(DOMConfigurator.java:415)



15:57:39,672 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:919)



15:57:39,673 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:790)



15:57:39,673 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:696)



15:57:39,674 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.configure(DOMConfigurator.java:821)



15:57:39,675 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer.initLogging(Log4jConfigurer.java:69)



15:57:39,676 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)



15:57:39,676 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)



15:57:39,677 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)



15:57:39,677 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)



15:57:39,678 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273)



15:57:39,678 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean.doInvoke(MethodInvokingFactoryBean.java:162)



15:57:39,679 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MethodInvokingFactoryBean.java:152)



15:57:39,679 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)



15:57:39,680 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)



15:57:39,681 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)



15:57:39,682 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)



15:57:39,683 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)



15:57:39,683 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)



15:57:39,684 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)



15:57:39,684 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)



15:57:39,685 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)



15:57:39,686 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)



15:57:39,686 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)



15:57:39,687 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)



15:57:39,688 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)



15:57:39,688 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at com.sanmar.service.ServiceFactory.getApplicationContext(ServiceFactory.java:26)



15:57:39,689 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at com.sanmar.service.ServiceFactory.getValidationService(ServiceFactory.java:37)



15:57:39,689 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at com.sanmar.service.integration.webservice.ejb.ValidationServiceBean.performValidationInventoryService(ValidationServiceBean.java:27)



15:57:39,690 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)



15:57:39,691 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)



15:57:39,691 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)



15:57:39,692 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)



15:57:39,692 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72)



15:57:39,693 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)



15:57:39,694 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)



15:57:39,694 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:36)



15:57:39,695 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)



15:57:39,695 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)



15:57:39,696 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)



15:57:39,696 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)



15:57:39,697 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)



15:57:39,697 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)



15:57:39,698 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53)



15:57:39,699 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)



15:57:39,699 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)



15:57:39,700 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)



15:57:39,700 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:228)



15:57:39,701 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304)



15:57:39,701 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190)



15:57:39,702 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)



15:57:39,702 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.EJBRemoteTransactionPropogatingInterceptor.processInvocation(EJBRemoteTransactionPropogatingInterceptor.java:80)



15:57:39,703 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)



15:57:39,704 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)



15:57:39,704 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)



15:57:39,705 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59)



15:57:39,705 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)



15:57:39,706 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)



15:57:39,707 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)



15:57:39,707 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45)



15:57:39,708 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)



15:57:39,708 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)



15:57:39,709 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165)



15:57:39,709 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:300)



15:57:39,710 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.access$200(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:64)



15:57:39,710 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler$1.run(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:194)



15:57:39,711 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)



15:57:39,712 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)



15:57:39,712 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)



15:57:39,713 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)



15:57:39,713 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)



15:57:39,714 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)



15:57:39,714 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)     at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)



15:57:39,715 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1) log4j:ERROR Could not parse url [file:D:/temp/properties/sm-enterprise-log4j.xml].



15:57:39,715 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1) java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I am using jboss modules and using log4j-1.2.16 module for logging. Can anybody helps me what have I do wrong with configuration or what. I have tried using jboss-deployment-structure.xml file

```
<deployment>

    <exclusions>

        <module name="org.apache.log4j" />

    </exclusions>

</deployment>

<sub-deployment name="BusinessComponent-1.1.jar">

    <exclusions>

        <module name="org.apache.log4j" />

    </exclusions>

</sub-deployment>

<sub-deployment name="sanmar-services-impl-1.1.jar">

    <exclusions>

        <module name="org.apache.log4j" />

    </exclusions>

</sub-deployment>
```

but no luck.

Link to Original post by me on jboss community discussion is 
https://community.jboss.org/thread/199439?tstart=0

Comment: These problems are often related to conflicting versions of log4j loaded with different class loaders.  Make sure you don't have the log4j JAR in your application archives - it is provided by JBoss.

Comment: No this is not the case. I think I am missing some specific configuration which anyone may point out. I am using jboss modules for log4j

Comment: Improve the SOF code formatting!

Answer (score 2):

This will be fixed in JBoss 7.2.x, but it's not released yet. So for older versions you need to [exclude](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+To#HowTo-HowdoIuselog4j.propertiesorlog4j.xmlinsteadofusingtheloggingsubsystemconfiguration%3F) the servers log4j library.

Answer (score 2):

Many more library will have to excluded. Found a working exclusion set here

http://tinyapps.blogspot.com/2013/01/getting-logback-and-slf4j-to-work-in.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies -->
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue in EAP 6.0 and AS 7 but the suggested solutions not works (worked perfectly in EAP 6.2 and AS 7.1.1).
In jboss-deployment-structure.xml file you don't have to exclude libraries like log4j, you have to include only the dependencies that application needs from JBOSS.
If your application needs no libs you can write:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```